# XML - python prints extra lines

Tags: python, xml, minidom

```
from xml import xpath
from xml.dom import minidom


xmldata = minidom.parse('model.xml').documentElement

for maks in xpath.Evaluate('/cacti/results/maks/text()', xmldata):
    print maks.nodeValue
```

And I get result:

85603399.14

398673062.66

95785523.81

But I needed to be:

85603399.14

NO SPACE

398673062.66

NO SPACE

95785523.81

Can somebody help me? I am new at programming

Comment: Please format your code block ([Ctrl]+[K]). Backticks only work on a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
print maks.nodeValue,
```

The comma at the end doesn't insert the extra newline.